# how to cancel a form of controller?

Tags: angularjs

help please cancel sending the form. after pressing the submit button to be displayed in the console message:

> stop submitForm! false

and sending the form should be blocked. because

```
$scope.message = false
```

js:

```
var briefApp = angular.module("briefApp", []);

briefApp.controller("briefController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.attachmentFilesize = false;
    $scope.attachmentFileformat = false;
    $scope.name = false;
    $scope.email = false;
    $scope.phone = false;
    $scope.message = false;

    $scope.submitForm = function (event) {
        if($scope.message == false){
            console.log('stop submitForm! false');
        }else{
            console.log('submitForm! true');
        }
    }    
})
```

html:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="brief_form_new" id="brief_form_new_test" action="#" method="post" novalidate="novalidate" ng-app="briefApp" ng-controller="briefController" ng-submit="submitForm()" >
    <textarea   type="text" 
                name="message_new" 
                rows="5" 
                cols="50" 
                class="main_field"
                placeholder="Я хочу... *" 
                style="width: 426px;" 
                title="Заполните поле"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="brief_submit_new" />
</form>
```

[fillde](http://jsfiddle.net/wTMv3/706/)

Comment: Cancel the default action: `<form ng-submit="submitForm($event)">` in the template and `$event.preventDefault();` in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `$event` from the view into the function   and then stop defualt event occurrence by preventDefault()

```
 ng-submit="submitForm($event)"
```

Controller

```
$scope.submitForm = function ($event) {
        if($scope.message == false){
            console.log('stop submitForm! false');
        }else{
            console.log('submitForm! true');
        }
       $event.preventDefault();
    }
```